# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I wrote the store procedure which should return the  values like-

```
J1
J2
J3
```

I have table named `Journal_Entry`. When the row count of the table is 0, it gives the result `J1` but as the row count increases it shows the error-

```
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'J' to data type int."
```

#here the `Voucher_No` is the column for the result to be saved.

The code is like-

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[getVoucherNo]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Prefix VARCHAR(10)='J'
    DECLARE @startFrom INT=1
    DECLARE @maxCode VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @sCode INT
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Journal_Entry) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @maxCode = CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(Voucher_No,LEN(@startFrom)+1,LEN(Voucher_No)- LEN(@Prefix)) AS INT)) AS varchar(100)) FROM dbo.Journal_Entry;
        SET @sCode=CAST(@maxCode AS INT)
        SELECT  @Prefix + LEN(CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(10))+1) + CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(100))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT(@Prefix + CAST(@startFrom AS VARCHAR)) 
    END

END
```

Comment: If at all possible, it would be better to store the prefix and the number in separate columns - it makes code such as the above drastically easier to write. If the prefix is always `J` that need not be stored at all. And you can always create a computed column that combines them back together in a single column, if you really need that.

Comment: I'm also struggling to understand why you'd `CAST` the `MAX` result *back* to a `varchar`, just to, on the next line, `CAST` it back to `int`.

Comment: actually i need the result as J1,J2 so that it can be showed in the application as voucher number and  also stored in the  single column.

Comment: you shouldn't base your database structure around your *display* or *formatting* requirements. Logically, the number and the prefix are two separate data items on which you want to perform processing - they ought to be in separate columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem located on the following line

```
SELECT  @Prefix + LEN(CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(10))+1) + CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(100))
```

Use this instead

```
SELECT  @Prefix + CAST(LEN(CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(10))+1) AS VARCHAR(100)) + CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(100))
```

Full Code:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[getVoucherNo]

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @Prefix VARCHAR(10)='J'

    DECLARE @startFrom INT=1

    DECLARE @maxCode VARCHAR(100)

    DECLARE @sCode INT

    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Journal_Entry) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @maxCode = CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(VoucharNo,LEN(@startFrom)+1,LEN(VoucharNo)- LEN(@Prefix)) AS INT))+1 AS varchar(100)) FROM dbo.Journal_Entry;
        SET @sCode=CAST(@maxCode AS INT)
        SELECT  @Prefix + CAST(LEN(CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(10))+1) AS VARCHAR(100)) + CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(100))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT(@Prefix + CAST(@startFrom AS VARCHAR)) 
    END
END
```

Comment: after editing it worked but why it is adding the number after the prefix 'J'?

Comment: @droid_rush, this answer identifies the same problem as my answer, just an hour later. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17568151/659190.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error message. In my case, it was due to not using quotes.

Although the column was supposed to have only numbers, it was a Varchar column, and one of the rows had a letter in it.

So I was doing this:

```
select * from mytable where myid = 1234
```

While I should be doing this:

```
select * from mytable where myid = '1234'
```

If the column had all numbers, the conversion would have worked, but not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seams to be located here:

```
SELECT @maxCode = CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(Voucher_No,LEN(@startFrom)+1,LEN(Voucher_No)- LEN(@Prefix)) AS INT)) AS varchar(100)) FROM dbo.Journal_Entry;
SET @sCode=CAST(@maxCode AS INT)
```

As the error says, you're casting a string that contains a letter 'J' to an `INT` which for obvious reasons is not possible.

Either fix `SUBSTRING` or don't store the letter 'J' in the database and only prepend it when reading.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
SELECT  @Prefix + LEN(CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(10))+1) + CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(100))
```

is wrong.

`@Prefix` is `'J'` and `LEN(...anything...)` is an `int`, hence the type mismatch.

---

It seems to me, you actually want to do,

```
SELECT
        @maxCode = MAX(
            CAST(SUBSTRING(
                Voucher_No,
                @startFrom + 1,
                LEN(Voucher_No) - (@startFrom + 1)) AS INT)
    FROM
        dbo.Journal_Entry;

SELECT  @Prefix + CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(10));
```

but, I couldn't say. If you illustrated before and after data, it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[getVoucherNo]
AS BEGIN

     DECLARE 
            @Prefix VARCHAR(10) = 'J'
          , @startFrom INT = 1
          , @maxCode VARCHAR(100)
          , @sCode INT

     IF EXISTS(
          SELECT 1 
          FROM dbo.Journal_Entry
     ) BEGIN

          SELECT @maxCode = CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(Voucher_No,LEN(@startFrom)+1,ABS(LEN(Voucher_No)- LEN(@Prefix))) AS INT)) AS varchar(100)) 
          FROM dbo.Journal_Entry;

          SELECT @Prefix + 
               CAST(LEN(LEFT(@maxCode, 10) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)) + -- !!! possible problem here
               CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(100))

     END
     ELSE BEGIN

          SELECT (@Prefix + CAST(@startFrom AS VARCHAR)) 

     END

END
```

Comment: `CAST` truncated value from @maxCode, so `CAST(@maxCode AS VARCHAR(10)` is equal to `LEFT(@maxCode, 10)`.